# Simplest approach to Node.js request serialisation

Tags: javascript, node.js, concurrency

I've got the classic asynchronous/concurrency problem that folks writing a service in Node.js at some point stumble into.  I have an object that fetches some data from an RDBM in response to a request, and emits a `fin` event (using an `EventEmitter`) when the row fetching is complete.

As you might expect, when the caller of the service makes several near-simultaneous calls to it, the rows are returned in an unpredictable order.  The `fin` event is fired for rows that do not correspond to the calling function's understanding of the request that produced them.

Here's what I've got going on (simplified for relevance):

```
var mdl = require('model.js');

dispatchGet: function(req, res, sec, params) {
    var guid = umc.genGUID(36);

    mdl.init(this.modelMap[sec], guid);

    // mdl.load() creates returns a 'new events.EventEmitter()'

    mdl.load(...).once('fin', 
      function() { 
        res.write(...);

        res.end();
      });

 }
```

A simple test shows that the `mdl.guid` often does not correspond to the `guid`.

I would have thought that creating a `new events.EventEmitter()` inside the `mdl.load()` function would fix this problem by creating a discrete `EventEmitter` for every request, but evidently that is not the case;  I suppose the same rules of object persistence apply to it as to any other object, irrespective of `new`.

I'm a C programmer by background: I can certainly come up with my own scheme for associating these replies with their requests, using some circular queue or hashing scheme.  However, I am guessing this problem has already been solved many times over.  My research has revealed many opinions on how to best handle this--various kinds of queuing implementations, `Futures`, etc.

What I'm wondering is, what's the simplest possible approach to good asynchronous flow control here?  I don't want to get knee-deep in some dependency's massive paradigm shift if I don't have to.  Is there a relatively simple, canonical, definitive solution, and/or widespread consensus on which third-party module is best?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could it be that your `model.js` looks something like this?

```
module.exports = {
  init : function(model, guid) {
    this.guid = guid;
    ...
  }
};
```

You have to be aware that the object you're passing to `module.exports` there is a shared object, in the sense that every other module that runs `require("model.js")` it will receive a reference *to the same object*.

So every time you run `mdl.init()`, the `guid` property of that object is changed, which would explain your comment that *"...a simple test shows that the mdl.guid often does not correspond to the guid"*.

It really depends on your exact implementation, but I think you'd want to use a class instead:

```
// model.js
var Mdl = function(model, guid) {
  this.guid  = guid;
};

Mdl.prototype.load = function() {
  // instantiate and return a new EventEmitter.
};

module.exports = Mdl;

// app.js
var Mdl = require('model.js');
...
var mdl = new Mdl(this.modelMap[sec], guid);
mdl.load(...)
```

Comment: Ah!  It seems that I simply do not understand JavaScript OO syntax and its relationship to Node innards.  Thank you!